# Cleaning Activities Data

Tags: apex, batch, data-loader

I'm trying to lower the storage usage.
I know that the archived Tasks is taking a lot of my storage.
I tried to do it several ways but still no success.
1. I used the Data Loader "Export All'. My query has some filters. However, even if I limit the result to 1000, I got error message the "query run too long"
2. I tried to write a batch apex to do this. I don't know how can I query the archived records in batch apex. Can I pass the query with a "All ROWs" signature to the class?
3. I am sure there's some tools can help me with this. Are there any mass delete apps also delete archived records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Dataloader with the Export All option, and include the isarchived=true filter with your other filters.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the best way that I have found to do this is through Setup. Go to Setup, Data Management, and then Mass Delete Records. From there, click on "Mass Delete Activities".

If you only want to clear out Tasks, make sure to set that as one of your filters.

Yes, this is kind of tedious, but it works!

Comment: Thank you! That interface only allows me to work on a few hundreds of records at a time. I have about 200,000 records to be removed.

Comment: Yes, the 250 limit is obnoxious, but it does move fairly quickly. Keep it in a separate window on your second monitor & you can blast through them faster than you think.

Just my 2 cents.